# Incorrect results in trig table

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a table given by

```
Table[
  Evaluate[
    Sum[(Sin[(2 π j x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1), {j, 0, r}]],
  {r, 1, 25}, {x, 0, 25}] /. Indeterminate -> 0
```

The expression `Indeterminate -> 0` is because of `Csc` in the expanded formula: the limit for integer `x` and `r` is always `0` because `Sin[0]=0`.

However, that's not what the table delivers. Instead, for some values of `x` and `r`, it gives a complicated expression rather than `0`.

How do I get round this?

Comment: Those expressions are in fact zeros. The trivial simplifications that are fast enough to be done automatically don't reduce them to zero. `Simplify` does though, e.g. `Simplify[1/10 ((-1 - Sqrt[5])/(4 Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8]) + (1 + Sqrt[5])/(
   4 Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8]))]`.  `PossibleZeroQ` also returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you. But when I try `Table[Evaluate[
   PossibleZeroQ[
    Sum[(Sin[(2 \[Pi] j x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1), {j, 0, r}]]], {r, 1, 
   25}, {x, 0, 25}] /. Indeterminate -> 0` I get `False`... And using `Simplify` in the `Table` context just gives different numbers, but still not `0`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  E.g. why do you need `Evaluate` in `Table`?  I was assuming that this is a simplified version of your real problem. It would help to know the constraints of your real problem. Otherwise just remove the `Evaluate` and wrap the whole `Table` in `Simplify`.

Comment: OK, that works. But why does `Evaluate` fail?

Comment: Do you understand what `Evaluate` does exactly here?

Comment: Evidently not... I'm a hobbyist. I got an A level way back in the mists of time. So I (naively) assume that something is right or wrong. If you evaluate something, you should get the right answer... But that clearly isn't how MMA works. And I do realise that you guys and gals don't want to invest loads of time into telling idiots like me the bleeding obvious (obvious to you, but not me!). So, apologies, and if you (collectively) don't want to help further, I totally understand. Many thanks. Richard

Comment: Richard, don't read anything more into my question than what I was asking. I am trying to write a helpful answer.  To be able to do that, I was trying to understand what exactly your misunderstanding was (if any).

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you. I wasn't trying to be sarcastic, I'm genuinely very grateful! But I do sometimes feel like MMA is a finely honed precision tool and I'm wielding it like a sledgehammer! Don't know quite what I'm doing...

Comment: First of all `Evaluate` in Mathematica has nothing to do with mathematics.  It's a programming construct. I suggest you look its precise function up in the documentation.  Now *in this specific case*: using `Evaluate` causes the sum to be computed for a generic, symbolic `r` and `x`.  Specific values of `x` and `r` are substituted in only afterwards.  Try evaluating `Sum[(Sin[(2 \[Pi] j x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1), {j, 0, r}]` alone in a separate cell to see the symbolic result.

Comment: As with the result of most symbolic computations in Mathematica, this is a "generic result". It's valid only for *almost* all `x` and `r` values. For a few it's not correct.  E.g. for `x -> 0, r -> 1` it's not valid, so you get `Indeterminate`.  `Sum` actually has a feature to try to also generate the conditions under which the result is correct. Try `Sum[(Sin[(2 \[Pi] j x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1), {j, 0, r}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]`.

Comment: If you don't use `Evaluate`, then the value of `x` and `r` are substituted in first, and the sum is only computed afterwards. Now Mathematica knows exacly how many terms to sum. It can do the summation explicitly. The results will be correct, and there won't be any `Indeterminate`s.

Comment: OK, that's really useful. Thank you. I need to go out now (posted the question at totally the wrong time!). But I'll do that. I think I have possibly been leaning on MMA in the wrong kind of way, assuming that it will deliver 'true' results, rather than the results of each highly specific input... Thanks @Szabolcs, I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: So the critical thing was the order of evaluations: do we evaluate the `Sum` first, and substitute values `r` and `x` afterwards, or the reverse. `Evaluate` is used for influencing the order of evaluations (but its behaviour is a bit complicated). The problem with `PossibleZeroQ` was the same. `PossibleZeroQ[x]` immediately returns `False` because the formula `x` is not zero for all values of `x`.  Thus even `PossibleZeroQ[x] /. x->0` returns `False`.  However, `PossibleZeroQ[x /. x -> 0]` returns `True`.

Comment: A more confusing situation is `OddQ[x]` returning `False` immediately (unless `x` had a value). That's because most `...Q` functions always returns either `True` or `False` immediately. `x` is a symbol (not an odd integer) so the result is `False`.  All these issues have to do with programming and the peculiarities of Mathematica, and have nothing to do with mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit Evaluate the result

```
Table[Sum[(Sin[(2 π j x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1), {j, 0, r}] , {r, 1,25}, {x, 0, 25}]
```

shows `0` instead of `Intermediate`